# A better anti-spam solution for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, advertising

I have [Mollom](https://drupal.org/project/mollom) and [HoneyPot](https://drupal.org/project/honeypot) set up and working. I tried various Captcha modules with images, etc. I even put a question field in the registration form using Mollom and HoneyPot. Although the answer isn't included anywhere in the page, spam bots still manage to register, activate, and post spam!

Could you recommend a better solution than what I have, to stop the spam?