# Users with no roles are getting onto my system

Tags: users, security, advertising

I am having an issue with my site, there are users accessing it and creating accounts without having a role.

[image: users with no roles]

Here we can see user roles is blank. From my understanding someone has found a weakness in our system and has exploited it to create accounts with no roles.

since the account has no role does this mean its not subjected to the rules of any role? Do these accounts have admin access to our site or would it be closer to anon users.

Is there any basic thing that I could do to stop people with no roles getting in? Or is there a way to see how a user with no role is created (understanding the process would help me fix the problem)?

**Edit 1**

Version: Drupal 7

Module: User 7.32

Module: LoginToboggan 7.x-1.4

Comment: Having no roles means having no exclusive access , for a better answer mention your drupal version , and some of third party modules installed in your site so maybe some one can recognize the weakness based on core or modules bug

Comment: By default fresh users have no roles, only implicit "authenticated" role. If you didn't disable account creation, everything is as it is supposed to be. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when i create a new account I have to have a role, these people or more likely bots are exploiting something to get inside without a role.

Comment: How long after the release of 7.32 did you actually update to it? It seems to me you may have been affected by drupalgeddon.. There have also been 3 security releases for drupal core since 7.32 which can be seen [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release?api_version%5B%5D=103)

Comment: @2pha sorry I couldn't tell you when we updated I've only been on the project for 2 months and the login was built near 3 years ago to the best of my knowledge. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Check out [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) and also the others it lists on the page.

Comment: I know this, that's why I asked how long after the release of 7.32 was the site upgraded (it may have only been upgraded a month ago). Simply upgrading to 7.32 would not fix a site that had already been compromised.

Comment: @2pha I agree that he should make sure his site isn't compromised. But looking at the screendump, this is surely the work of *XRumer*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with no roles are how the default "Authenticated user" role is listed.  I.e. these have the access level that the system gives the role ""Authenticated user".

This by itself is nothing to be concerned about.

If you don't want to allow bots and fly-by users to create accounts, navigate to *Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings* and under *Registration and cancellation*, click that only admins can create new accounts.

If you want people to able to create accounts, but not bots, you need to let the registration process tell bots and humans apart.  One of these modules *may* help:

- [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) - See also: [How to add CAPTCHA to registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha)
- In particular; [CAPTCHA Riddler](https://drupal.org/project/riddler)
- [Mother May I](https://www.drupal.org/project/mothermayi)

However, in 2015, bots like [XRumer](http://www.botmasterlabs.net/product17632/) *knows* how to do *most* CAPTCHAs including math and "warped" letters - you may need to experiment a bit to find a CAPTCHA configuration that works.

But preventing spam registrations are actually the topic of this question: [Unknown User Registered into my system](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118525/unknown-user-registered-into-my-system)

Comment: so these people are default users? On my system they need to pick a role to create an account, there should never be a situation where they can get in without a role. thanks for the info on "Authenticated user" roles btw

Comment: I do want people to be able to create accounts just not ones with no roles as they are clearly violating the create account process. 

I know bots will still try to create accounts but my assumption is they should come in as a "simple user" (an account with an unverified email)

Comment: you can use a captcha in your registration form so humans can create an account but not the bots

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining this wrong sorry. So when someone is making an account there are 4 choices for 4 different types none of these choices would let a user make and account with the role "Authenticated user". what I mean to ask is how are bots able to make "Authenticated user" accounts when there is no basic path to make that type of user?

Comment: Bots do *exactly* the same thing as humans: They "click" on the link to create a user on your site's home page, and then fill out the form with a user name and an email address. If you require email verification, then the bot is programmed to go trough with that process as well. Some of the bots even know how to solve CAPTCHAs.

Comment: If your not into captchas, maybe [honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) or even [antibot](https://www.drupal.org/project/antibot) would be good (or a combination). I never use captchas and don't have much of a problem with bots